# How to do redirection with cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want two types of domain redirects on the same site (if else statement etc):

```
If user has cookie:
And url subdomain is amazon then redirect to url xxxxxx
And url subdomain is ebay then redirect to url xxxx

If user has no cookie:
And url subdomain amazon then first forward to ebay subdomain and back to amazon subdomain once (currently creates a loop) and display background xxxx with href link xxxx
And url subdomain ebay then first forward to amazon subdomain and back to ebay subdomain once (currently creates a loop) and display background xxxx with href link xxxx
```

Synchronise user cross-domain click for a new pop-up for href xxxxx - ie if user has come on site by clicking on link on another site then see asynchronise click to open another pop-up (200 sec rule)

Currently site already has below which I still need, so cookie redirect shouldn't set a redirect to site outside because of the code below but only if user is genuinely a returning user

```js
var subdomain = window.location.hostname.split('.')[0];
if (!document.cookie == null && subdomain === "amazon") {
  window.location = "http://www..com";
} else if (!document.cookie == null && subdomain === "ebay") {
  window.location = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com";
} else if (document.cookie == null && subdomain === "amazon") {
  var oLinksArray = [];
  oLinksArray[0] = 'http://www.ebay.com';
  oLinksArray[1] = 'http://www.amazon.com';
  for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    var openWindow = window.open(oLinksArray[x]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      openWindow.close();
    }, 2000);
  }
} else if (document.cookie == null && subdomain === "ebay") {
  var oLinksArray = [];
  oLinksArray[0] = 'http://www.amazon.com';
  oLinksArray[1] = 'http://www.ebay.com';
  for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    var openWindow = window.open(oLinksArray[x]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      openWindow.close();
    }, 2000);
  }

} else {}
```

Comment: Kindly share the code where you have attempted to do this. It will help the community in understanding your problem.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to transfer cookie with redirection. `Cookie` has a property called `domain`. You should add website's domains to give access permission to them.

**In Javascript**

```
var cookieName = 'HelloWorld';
var cookieValue = 'HelloWorld';
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate 
                  + ";domain=firstDomain.com,nextDomain.com;path=/";
```

**In PHP**

```
setcookie('mycookie','mydata1',time() + 2*7*24*60*60,'/','www.firstDomain.com,nextDomain.com', false);
```